# Блокировка файла на запись или чтение

Tags: файлы, golang

Как можно заблокировать файл на чтение/запись в Go, для параллельных потоков работающих с одним файлом?

Comment: Потоков или процессов? Если для потоков, то мутекс.

Comment: я запускаю два потока `go foo1()  go foo2()` и в первом например записываю в файл во втором читаю из тогоже файла, как сделать, чтоб они не конфликтовали

Comment: Мне кажется, вы пытаетесь сделать очень странную вещь, которая может привести к "весёлым" логическим гонкам. Почему просто не передавать данные между горутинами через каналы?

Comment: @Ainar-G у меня есть 2 функции запускаемые параллельно они одновременно с одним файлом обновляя в нем данные, функции по идее должны работать через разные разные периоды времени, но есть вероятность что в какой то момен они будут работать одновременно

Comment: Если доступ к файлу одновременно должен быть только у одной горутины, надо использовать `sync.Mutex`. Если такой вариант вас устроит, могу написать ответ с ним.

Comment: Окей, ща попробую

Comment: @Ainar-G , если не сложно, напишите пример, то что находил в интернете, как по мне, не работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вам нужна синхронизация в рамках одной программы, используйте [`sync.Mutex`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex).

```
var mu = &sync.Mutex{}

func writeFile(name string) {
    for {
        func() {
            mu.Lock()
            defer mu.Unlock()
            // Write file...
        }()
    }
}

func readFile(name string) {
    for {
        func() {
            mu.Lock()
            defer mu.Unlock()
            // Read file...
        }()
    }
}
```

Полный пример программы, которая читает и пишет файл в разных горутинах тут: https://play.golang.org/p/p1ieKznJTlu.